# Rigorous proof of Fluid Flux with Linear Algebra

Tags: fluid-dynamics, linear-algebra

In fluid mechancics the flux is the volume that passes through a surface in a unit time. To do the easiest case to then build up to the integral, I want to look at a square surface in a time-invariant, location independent velocity field (a velocity field constant in both time and space).

$\mathbf{v}(x,y,z,t)=\mathbf{v}$

I believe the problem can be formulated in the following way. The set of the positions at $t_{0}$ of the particles that in the time interval $(t_{0},t_{0}+T)$ cross the surface is the set

$\{\mathbf{x}(t_{0}) | \exists t\in(t_{0},t_{0}+T) : \mathbf{x}(t_{0})+t\mathbf{v}\in S  \}$ where S is the set of points in the square

Intuitively, this set is the set of all points in the cuboid formed by the square surface and 4 $-T\mathbf{v}$ vectors placed at each corner of the square. I do not know how to rigorously get to this answer however.

Comment: I would suggest writing up the set of this cuboid. The equivalence of the sets should be evident quite soon as you will arrive to the same construction as your original set (albeit with some minus signs). Basically, your cuboid consists of elements of $S$ translated (back) by $-t\boldsymbol{v}$ for $t\in(0,T)$.